# Does a wizard need to decipher a scroll he scribes?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, magic-items, wizard

Does a wizard need to complete the first step of casting a spell from a scroll by deciphering the script if he himself scribed the scroll?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the purpose of deciphering the scroll is to learn what spells it contains - if you already know the answer, you can skip that step.

> Deciphering a scroll ***to determine its contents*** (emphasis mine) does not activate its magic unless it is a specially prepared cursed scroll.

As for why, the description of how scrolls are activated indicates that you're basically casting the spell as you would normally, just using magic stored in the scroll instead. This suggests that you have to tailor your actions to the specific spell.